# Why do the protagonist seem to suddenly understand the people of Facade?

Tags: nier-replicant-1.22474487139

I find it weird that when you get to Facade, the protagonist can't seem to understand anything people say.

But after a major story event, suddenly you seem to be able to understand the residents of facade. But I guess I missed it, because there doesn't seem to be any reason why suddenly you understand them. Its not like you learned their language or they suddenly decided to talk in english (and were just dicks before). Its probably the first option because their captions are between parenteses, which usually denotes that they are speaking in something that is not english, but the protagonist still understands them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so much that the protagninst learns to understand the people of Facade, it's *Weiss* who learns to understand them.

During your first visit Facade, the dialogue with residents lacks said parathesis you mentioned (indicating they are speaking, but you do not understand them). Weiss is amazed and comments on how they speak a language he has never encountered before. When you meet the young girl who speaks through (I guess sign language and interpretive dance), Weiss begins to slowly learn their language while speaking with her and taking the tour of Facade. Throughout this tour, Weiss takes a lot of pauses while translating their language back to you.

After the tour is complete is when the dialogue starts to readable, and the protagonist seems to somehow "understand" them. What is really happening is that Weiss learns their language and translate back to you real-time so ... you ... don't ... have .... to ... sit ... there ... waiting ... for ... the ... dialogue